# Processing updating text and function parameters

Tags: python, function, parameters, parameter-passing, processing

This is my very first post on this website, and hopefully I can get some valuable insight and hints in regards to my problem as I'm a relative noob when it comes to programming. I am using Python mode in the Processing environment.

I was given a lecture problem (that the teacher will eventually go over) but I wanted to be able to solve it beforehand. Unfortunately I am not sure how to. I'm supposed to create a program that displays the amount of buns, franks and hotdogs that can be made from the amount of buns and franks, and I have keyboard inputs to increase the amount that is displayed for buns and franks.

Currently, I can't figure out how to get my text to update when I enter keyboard inputs nor can I figure out how to automatically update the number of hotdogs based on the amount of buns and franks I have.

I have attached two pictures of the question that will clear up any confusion if my explanation was not clear. I have also attached the current code I have.

[picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhC1g.png)
[picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LrjHS.png)

Code:

```
    #Variables/Model
    meat = ""
    buns = ""
    dogs = min(12 * meat, 8 * buns)


    def setup():
        size(400,400)


    def draw():
        global meat, buns, dogs
        background(255)
        meat = 0
        buns = 0
        dogs = min(12 * meat, 8 * buns)
        fill(0)
        text("Packages of meat:" + str(meat), 50, 100)
        text("Packages of buns:" + str(buns), 250, 100)
        text("Dogs possibly made:" + str(dogs), 150, 200)


    def make_hotdogs(totalMeat, totalBuns):
        global meat, buns, dogs
        if keyPressed == "f":
            meat += 1
        elif keyPressed == "g":
            meat -= 1
        elif keyPressed == "b":
            buns += 1
        elif keyPressed == "n":
            buns -= 1
        else:
            print("Type b, n, f or g")
```

Comment: What is the function `text()`? Which GUI toolkit did you use? (Show your imports)

Answer (score 0):

You're never calling your `make_hotdogs()` function, so you're never hitting the `if` statements that check which key is pressed.

You might want to look into the `keyPressed()` function. You can find more info in [the reference](http://py.processing.org/reference/keyPressed.html).

But honestly, if you're confused, maybe you should just wait for the teacher to explain everything in the lecture.

Comment: Would I be calling this function just on its own, not under any other function?

Comment: @GrapeJuice Processing automatically calls the `keyPressed()` function for you, similar to how it automatically calls the `setup()` and `draw()` functions.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got the logic working. I changed the keyboard input to keyPressed and then I made my make_hotdog function just give a return value of what I want the hotdog number to be. But I still can't get the keyboard inputs to actually change any of the numbers on the screen.

Comment: @GrapeJuice You're going to have to debug your program. Is the `keyPressed()` function being called? Which `if` statements are being executed? Try to narrow it down to an updated [mcve] and post that in a new post if you have follow-up questions. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's been a week so let's assume that *lecture* has taken place and let's solve this problem.  The issues I see with the OP's code is a lack of understanding of basic Python and the Processing environment.  And a failure to take advantange of the problem terminology that's been provided.

Reworking the code to address the above issues and generate a viable picnic planner that runs in the Processing environment:

```
# Variables/Model

FRANKS_PER_PACKAGE = 12
BUNS_PER_PACKAGE = 8

frank_packages = 0
bun_packages = 0

def setup():
    size(400, 400)
    fill(0)  # black text on a
    background(255)  # white background

def draw():
    hotdogs = make_hotdogs(frank_packages, bun_packages)

    text("Packages of franks: " + str(frank_packages), 50, 100)
    text("Packages of buns: " + str(bun_packages), 250, 100)
    text("Hotdogs possibly made: " + str(hotdogs), 150, 200)

def keyPressed():
    global frank_packages, bun_packages

    if key == "f":
        frank_packages += 1
    elif key == "g":
        if frank_packages > 0:
            frank_packages -= 1
    elif key == "b":
        bun_packages += 1
    elif key == "n":
        if bun_packages > 0:
            bun_packages -= 1

    background(255)  # white out old calculations

def make_hotdogs(p_franks, p_buns):
    return min(p_franks * FRANKS_PER_PACKAGE, p_buns * BUNS_PER_PACKAGE)
```

With the exception of `make_hotdocs()`, the Processing environment calls these functions for us.  It calls `setup()` once at the start of the program; it calls `draw()` continuously over and over again; it calls `keyPressed()` whenever the user types on the keyboard, leaving the letter pressed in the `key` variable.

In Python, we only need to declare `global` variables where we plan to change their values, not where we simply intend to use their values.